# Linux Chat Server Design

Tags: centos, instant-messaging

I develop an PHP/Ajax based live chat system and host in simple Virtualmin Based CentOS server, I want to know what type of changes we do in server that make our chatting process fast.

Comment: There is nowhere near enough information there for us to even guess.  What have you tried so far to diagnose the slowness?

Answer (score 1):

PROGRAM IT GOOD!

And don't use PHP.